# Eliminate characters between numbers in Lex code

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

How can I eliminate characters between two or more integer numbers in lex code?

Ex:12bd35

output:12 35

Answer (score 1):

Lex builds lexical analyzers, which are intended to split the input into separate tokens. Once you recognize a token, you can ignore it, which is somewhat similar to "eliminating characters". But you always need to recognise them.

So you might start with the following minimalist scanner:

```
%option noinput nounput noyywrap
%%
[[:digit:]]+  { ECHO; fputc(' ', yyout); } /* print numbers.
[^[:digit:]]+ ;    /* ignore everything else. */
```

And then modify it to fit your actual need.